# “Transform Sample File” feature when getting data from Sharepoint

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, data-transform

I'm importing multiple excel spreadsheet from Sharepoint. Unfortunately, the tabs are inconsistent, and I'd like to use a "Sheet index" instead of Sheet name as explained on this [page](https://radacad.com/get-data-from-multiple-excel-files-with-different-sheet-names-into-power-bi). However, I cannot seem to find the "Transform Sample File" option for this particular query. Is it available for Sharepoint source or is there another way to reference Sheet index?